# Dynamic Filtering using variable in filter function in Flux

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

Using the quantile function, I was able to get 95 % percentile value in a stream.

Now, i want to filter records which lie below the 95% percentile.
hence, I loop over my recods and filter records which lie below the percentile.
However, at this topic I get error –

Please find code below –

```
percentile = totalTimeByDoc
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["documentType"] == "PurchaseOrder")
  
  |> group(columns:["documentType"])
//   |> yield()
  |> quantile(column: "processTime", q: 0.95, method: "estimate_tdigest", compression: 9999.0)
  |> limit(n: 1)
  |> rename(columns: {processTime: "pt"})
```

Gives me data – >

```
0 PurchaseOrder 999
```

Now, I try to loop over my records and filter -

```
 percentile_filered = totalTimeByDoc
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["documentType"] == "PurchaseOrder")
   |> filter(fn: (r) => r.processTime < percentile[0]["pt"])
     |> yield()
```

Where, totalTimeByDoc is like below –

```
|0|PurchaseOrder|testpass22PID230207222747-1|1200|

|1|PurchaseOrder|testpass22PID230207222747-2|807|
|2|PurchaseOrder|testpass22PID230207222934-1|671|
|3|PurchaseOrder|testpass22PID230207222934-2|670|
```

I get following error from above query –

```
 error @116:41-116:51: expected [{A with pt: B}] (array) but found stream[{A with pt: B}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only missing column extraction from *percentile* stream. Have a look at [Extract scalar values](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.6/query-data/flux/scalar-values/). In this very case, you could do

```js
percentile = totalTimeByDoc
  |> ...
  |> rename(columns: {processTime: "pt"})
  |> findColumn(fn: (key) => true, column: "pt")

percentile_filtered = totalTimeByDoc
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["documentType"] == "PurchaseOrder")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.processTime < percentile[0])
  |> yield()
```